# RMySQL error 'configure' exists but is not executable

Tags: centos, rmysql

I am installing RMySQL on centos.
There were many dependencies, and I was able to install all.

But still getting one error, when I am trying to install.

The command I am executing is below:

> R CMD INSTALL RMySQL_0.9-3.tar

And I am getting following errors:

```
* installing to library /usr/lib64/R/library
* installing *source* package RMySQL ...
ERROR: 'configure' exists but is not executable -- see the 'R Installation and
* removing /usr/lib64/R/library/RMySQL
```

Has anybody faced this kind of problem with Rphp or RMySQL ?

Thanks in Advance for reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was permission issue.

And it was solved by the commands

```
# chmod 777 /root/tmp/ 
# TMPDIR=$HOME/tmp 
# export TMPDIR
```

I am posting my answer here, hope it will help someone else also.